# Formatting and incrementing a Django form in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, forms

OK so I have a running form in Django that updates the model and displays this on the page, but I was hoping to better format it. What happens is that the page displays all data imputed in the form. What I want to do is to numerically list it. This is what I have in my home.html right now:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}

<div class="container">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h2>Object:{{ post.post }}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

So say I have data "a", "b", and "c". It would display itself as

Object: a

Object: b

Object: c

If I added d to the form, it would add

Object: d

What I'm hoping to do is add an increment to this so it displays itself as

Object 1: a

Object 2: b

Object 3: c

And add d as

Object 4:

How would I go about implementing this? Another thing I wanted to know is whether I can change the "Post:" comment next to the form. Right now my form displays itself with "Post:" at the left side. Is there a way to edit this?

EDIT: Here's my view.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from firstapp.forms import IndexForm
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from firstapp.models import Post

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = IndexForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all()
        args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = IndexForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = IndexForm()
            return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Comment: can you show the code for the view?

Comment: Added the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want to do is to numerically list it

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#for

You're looking for "forloop.counter":

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <h2>Object {{ forloop.counter }}: {{ post.post }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

> Right now my form displays itself with "Post:" at the left side. Is there a way to edit this?

It looks like this is because your model is called "Post".

```
from firstapp.models import Post
```

By using the:

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Django will render a default set of form fields and labels.  You can override the way those forms fields are displayed by modifying your IndexForm class, or manually render the entire form yourself in your home.html.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#form-rendering-options